# Add new key value to all the elements in array of dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a array of dictionary.
I need to add a new key and a value to all the elements of array of dictionary.

Please guide.

Comment: Have you read the Swift Language Guide already? It explains how to iterate over a collection type like array and also how to add elements to a dictionary: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the dictionary from the array, modify it and put back to the array, since arrays and dictionaries in Swift are value types.

Something like this should work for you:

```
var arrayofDict = [["1": 1], ["2": 2], ["3": 3]]

for i in 0..<arrayofDict.count {
    var dict = arrayofDict[i]
    dict["random"] = Int(arc4random_uniform(8)) //random integer value
    arrayofDict[i] = dict
}

print(arrayofDict) //prints "[["1": 1, "random": 2], ["2": 2, "random": 0], ["random": 2, "3": 3]]\n"
```

Comment: Another requirement is, once i prepare the final array of dictionary... I want to delete the entire dictionary which will have a key as "random" and value as 2... For the output only ["2": 2, "random": 0] should be present and rest removed.